# How do I install Brackets IDE from behind a firewall on Linux?

Tags: linux, installation, npm, firewall, adobe-brackets

We are behind a firewall.

We have a self-hosted central npm repository, that doesn't have all the packages (most, but not all).

It seems the grunt build process (to compile from source) relies on phantomjs to be built via npm. I have phantomjs 1.9.2 built from source and available, but the process specifies that it needs to be installed via npm to work.

My goal is to build so I can use the IDE in my environment. There is a .app, and a .msi available for Wndows and Mac, but for Linux I have to compile from source (we have a .deb, but I'm on CentOS).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't actually need PhantomJS for building Brackets -- I see it's a dependency in the package.json, but I don't actually see a mention in the Brackets source code where it may be called.
So could you just try building Brackets without having PhantomJS installed and see if it works?

Comment: Yea, i'm trying to circumnavigate the build script. I haven't been successful yet.

Comment: The Brackets source shouldn't be the main problem though, the real problem is [the shell](https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell). If you are unable to build Brackets, you could just copy the whole git repository content (with submodules installed!) over to the `www` folder of your local shell. The shell, though, has to be built...